# Using project layers as input to the graphical modeler exported script in the Python console (QGIS)

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-modeler

I have created an workflow wothin graphical modeler in QGIS. 
Now I want to use the code exported from the graphical modeler in the python console.

How could I use the layers from my project as input to the code?

In the following code,for exemple, there are 3 necessary inputs: DEM (raster), slope (raster) and a buffer_user (vector).

'

```
def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):
    self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterVectorLayer('bufferuser', 'Buffer_User', types=[QgsProcessing.TypeVectorPolygon], defaultValue=None))
    self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterRasterLayer('dem', 'DEM', defaultValue=None))
    self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterRasterLayer('slope', 'Slope', defaultValue=None))
    self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterVectorDestination('Cp', 'CP', type=QgsProcessing.TypeVectorAnyGeometry, createByDefault=True, defaultValue=None))
    self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterVectorDestination('Centroid', 'centroid', type=QgsProcessing.TypeVectorAnyGeometry, createByDefault=True, defaultValue=None))

def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, model_feedback):
    # Use a multi-step feedback, so that individual child algorithm progress reports are adjusted for the
    # overall progress through the model
    feedback = QgsProcessingMultiStepFeedback(12, model_feedback)
    results = {}
    outputs = {}

    # Calculadora de campo
    alg_params = {
        'FIELD_LENGTH': 10,
        'FIELD_NAME': 'Raio_buffer_user_X1.3',
        'FIELD_PRECISION': 3,
        'FIELD_TYPE': 0,
        'FORMULA': '((length(shortest_line(centroid($geometry),boundary($geometry)))))*1.3',
        'INPUT': parameters['bufferuser'],
        'NEW_FIELD': True,
        'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
    }
    outputs['CalculadoraDeCampo'] = processing.run('qgis:fieldcalculator', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

    feedback.setCurrentStep(1)
    if feedback.isCanceled():
        return {}

    # Polygon centroids
    alg_params = {
        'METHOD         ': True,
        'POLYGONS': outputs['CalculadoraDeCampo']['OUTPUT'],
        'CENTROIDS': parameters['Centroid']
    }
    outputs['PolygonCentroids'] = processing.run('saga:polygoncentroids', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)
    results['Centroid'] = outputs['PolygonCentroids']['CENTROIDS']

    feedback.setCurrentStep(2)
    if feedback.isCanceled():
        return {}

    # Buffer de distância variável
    alg_params = {
        'DISSOLVE': False,
        'END_CAP_STYLE': 0,
        'FIELD': 'Raio_buffer_user_X1.3',
        'INPUT': outputs['PolygonCentroids']['CENTROIDS'],
        'JOIN_STYLE': 0,
        'MITER_LIMIT': 2,
        'SEGMENTS': 5,
        'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
    }
    outputs['BufferDeDistnciaVarivel'] = processing.run('qgis:variabledistancebuffer', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

    feedback.setCurrentStep(3)
    if feedback.isCanceled():
        return {}

    # Adicionar atributos de geometria
    alg_params = {
        'CALC_METHOD': 0,
        'INPUT': outputs['PolygonCentroids']['CENTROIDS'],
        'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
    }
    outputs['AdicionarAtributosDeGeometria'] = processing.run('qgis:exportaddgeometrycolumns', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

    feedback.setCurrentStep(4)
    if feedback.isCanceled():
        return {}

    # Polígonos para linhas
    alg_params = {
        'INPUT': outputs['BufferDeDistnciaVarivel']['OUTPUT'],
        'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
    }
    outputs['PolgonosParaLinhas'] = processing.run('native:polygonstolines', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

    feedback.setCurrentStep(5)
    if feedback.isCanceled():
        return {}

    # Densificar por intervalo
    alg_params = {
        'INPUT': outputs['PolgonosParaLinhas']['OUTPUT'],
        'INTERVAL': 600,
        'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
    }
    outputs['DensificarPorIntervalo'] = processing.run('native:densifygeometriesgivenaninterval', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

    feedback.setCurrentStep(6)
    if feedback.isCanceled():
        return {}

    # Extrair vértices
    alg_params = {
        'INPUT': outputs['DensificarPorIntervalo']['OUTPUT'],
        'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
    }
    outputs['ExtrairVrtices'] = processing.run('native:extractvertices', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

    feedback.setCurrentStep(7)
    if feedback.isCanceled():
        return {}

    # Adicionar atributos de geometria
    alg_params = {
        'CALC_METHOD': 0,
        'INPUT': outputs['ExtrairVrtices']['OUTPUT'],
        'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
    }
    outputs['AdicionarAtributosDeGeometria'] = processing.run('qgis:exportaddgeometrycolumns', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

    feedback.setCurrentStep(8)
    if feedback.isCanceled():
        return {}

    # Unir atributos pelo valor do campo
    alg_params = {
        'DISCARD_NONMATCHING': False,
        'FIELD': 'Drawings',
        'FIELDS_TO_COPY': None,
        'FIELD_2': 'Drawings',
        'INPUT': outputs['AdicionarAtributosDeGeometria']['OUTPUT'],
        'INPUT_2': outputs['AdicionarAtributosDeGeometria']['OUTPUT'],
        'METHOD': 1,
        'PREFIX': '',
        'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
    }
    outputs['UnirAtributosPeloValorDoCampo'] = processing.run('native:joinattributestable', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

    feedback.setCurrentStep(9)
    if feedback.isCanceled():
        return {}

    # XY to line
    alg_params = {
        'DateLineBreak': False,
        'EndUseLayerGeom': False,
        'EndXField': 'xcoord',
        'EndYField': 'ycoord',
        'InputCRS': 'ProjectCrs',
        'InputLayer': outputs['UnirAtributosPeloValorDoCampo']['OUTPUT'],
        'LineType': 0,
        'OutputCRS': 'ProjectCrs',
        'ShowEndPoint': True,
        'ShowStartPoint': True,
        'StartUseLayerGeom': False,
        'StartXField': 'xcoord_2',
        'StartYField': 'ycoord_2',
        'OutputLineLayer': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
    }
    outputs['XyToLine'] = processing.run('shapetools:xy2line', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

    feedback.setCurrentStep(10)
    if feedback.isCanceled():
        return {}

    # Profiles from lines
    alg_params = {
        'DEM': parameters['dem'],
        'LINES': outputs['XyToLine']['OutputLineLayer'],
        'NAME': 'Drawings',
        'SPLIT         ': False,
        'VALUES': [],
        'PROFILE': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT,
        'PROFILES': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
    }
    outputs['ProfilesFromLines'] = processing.run('saga:profilesfromlines', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

    feedback.setCurrentStep(11)
    if feedback.isCanceled():
        return {}

    # Add raster values to points
    alg_params = {
        'GRIDS': parameters['slope'],
        'RESAMPLING': 0,
        'SHAPES': outputs['ProfilesFromLines']['PROFILES'],
        'RESULT': parameters['Cp']
    }
    outputs['AddRasterValuesToPoints'] = processing.run('saga:addrastervaluestopoints', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)
    results['Cp'] = outputs['AddRasterValuesToPoints']['RESULT']
    return results

def name(self):
    return 'Modelo_2_crater_delineation'

def displayName(self):
    return 'Modelo_2_crater_delineation'

def group(self):
    return ''

def groupId(self):
    return ''

def createInstance(self):
    return Modelo_2_crater_delineation()
```

'

Comment: If you run a model from the python console, you may need to define all parameters used. So 3 inputs and 2 outputs. Try using something like: `processing.run(model:my_model, {'bufferuser': some_path, 'dem': some_path, 'slope': some_path, 'Cp': some_path, 'Centroid': some_path})`